# MS Dynamics CRM Quick Search

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, quick-search

I would like to look for record among records of entities Leads, Opportunities, Accounts. That's mean I can select Leads from Sales and after that I can to find records from Leads, Opportunities and Accounts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question that you'd like to search across more than one entity in one search. That you would like your query to be searched in Leads, Opportunities and Accounts in the same time. In the OOTB functionality you cannot do this, however the guys over at PowerObjects has a third party solution for this kind of stuff called PowerGlobalSearch. You can read about it here and see if it's something that could help you: http://www.powerobjects.com/add-on-subscriptions/powerpack/powerglobalsearch/